# How do I know that a /dev/dm-XX device isn't used by anything on SLES 10.4 (64bit)?

Tags: linux, raid, sles

I have a device that I can see in the output of `fdisk -l`:

```
/dev/dm-XX
```

(`XX` is a number.)

How do I know that I can use this `/dev/dm-XX` to add it to a RAID1 array? How can I be 100% sure that nothing is using this `/dev/dm-XX`?

Comment: This is indeed a field in which Linux / LVM2 can improve. It requires a bit of puzzling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo fuser /dev/dm-31
/dev/dm-31:          24799
ps -fp 24799
vbox     24799     1  2 May18 ?        04:37:39 /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxHeadle.....
```

or when using LVM2 (on Ubuntu, SLES may vary in detail):

```
ls -l /dev/mapper | grep dm-1$
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 May 11 19:01 vg_diablo-var -> ../dm-1
```

You may also want to check `man dmsetup` eg. `dmsetup info`

Comment: `dmsetup info` is the command to use - mainly the information about Open count. DM target can be opened/used for example by making a LVM volume group active, or by mounting a filesystem on LVM logical volume.